# Append binary using update in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have binary data in specific field in sql server 2008,
but i want to append some binary data to the same field.
can you help me about that?

Comment: `varbinary(max)` or `image` ? it matters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it is a `varbinary(n)` / `varbinary(max)` - you just append with `+`:

```
declare @foo table(id int, bar varbinary(max))

insert @foo values(1, 0x01)

declare @newdata varbinary(max) = 0x020304

update @foo set bar = bar + @newdata
where id = 1

select bar from @foo
where id = 1
```

If you are using `image`, you can use [`UPDATETEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189466.aspx), but it is more involved (read MSDN) - `insert_offset` of `NULL` means "append", and specify `delete_length` of `0`.